# Authenticating user problem with django-tenant-schema

Tags: django

I want to have admin module available to tenants (using `django-tenant-schema`).
My apps section of settings.py:

```
# Application definition
SHARED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app
    'customers', # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in

    # 'django.contrib.sites',

    # everything below here is optional


)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # your tenant-specific apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app

    'customers',
    # 'django.contrib.sites', #using this will cause error - see my stackoverflow question
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

I have set up 2 schemas (tenant1 and public). Created superuser and can see that superuser is created within tenant1 schema. However when trying to log in at tenant1.domain.com/admin, getting login screen but after entering credentials keep getting:

> ProgrammingError at /admin/login/ relation "auth_user" does not exist

Looks like it is not picking up my tenant1 schema?
What I have to change in configuration?

Comment: Do you have the tenant middleware installed? it's responsible for negotiating which tenant is called and connecting to the right schemas.

Comment: Thank you. This sort out the problem. How I can mark this as solution?

Comment: You could mark the answer below as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure tenant middleware is installed.

It's responsible for negotiating which tenant is called and connecting to the right schemas.